# joining only lines with spaces in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the below data.. where you can see spaces between 2 lines in the beginning and no spaces in between some other lines:

```
Report Area

Total Population

Total Land Area
(Square Miles)

Population Density 
(Per Square Mile)


Report Area 37,325,068 155,738.02 239.67 
Alameda County, CA 1,515,136 738.82 2,050.75 
Alpine County, CA 1,197 738.13 1.62 
Amador County, CA 37,764 594.43 63.53 
Butte County, CA 220,101 1,636.03 134.53 
Calaveras County, CA 45,507 1,019.74 44.63 
Colusa County, CA 21,329 1,150.43 18.54
```

I need the final output as this:

```
Report Area  Total Population  Total Land Area(Square Miles)  Population Density(Per Square Mile)

Report Area 37,325,068 155,738.02 239.67 
Alameda County, CA 1,515,136 738.82 2,050.75 
Alpine County, CA 1,197 738.13 1.62 
Amador County, CA 37,764 594.43 63.53 
Butte County, CA 220,101 1,636.03 134.53 
Calaveras County, CA 45,507 1,019.74 44.63 
Colusa County, CA 21,329 1,150.43 18.54
```

I have tried using `output = " ".join(line.strip(  ) for line in f)`
but it doesnt work as I need.

this is my output:

```
Report Area  Total Population  Total Land Area (Square Miles)  Population Density (Per Square Mile)   Report Area 37,325,068 155,738.02 239.67 Alameda County, CA 1,515,136 738.82 2,050.75 Alpine County, CA 1,197 738.13 1.62 Amador County, CA 37,764 594.43 63.53
```

all the lines in a single line..

Comment: I think I've edited your formatting correctly. I was unsure about your final output though. Please check that my edit is correct. If not, adjust it as needed.

Comment: you are right Andy.. that is how I want my output.. Thanks for Editing.. ;)

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import re
p = re.compile(ur'\n\n|\n(?=[^\n]*\n\n)', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"Report Area\n\nTotal Population\n\nTotal Land Area\n(Square Miles)\n\nPopulation Density \n(Per Square Mile)\n\n\nReport Area 37,325,068 155,738.02 239.67 \nAlameda County, CA 1,515,136 738.82 2,050.75 \nAlpine County, CA 1,197 738.13 1.62 \nAmador County, CA 37,764 594.43 63.53 \nButte County, CA 220,101 1,636.03 134.53 \nCalaveras County, CA 45,507 1,019.74 44.63 \nColusa County, CA 21,329 1,150.43 18.54 "
subst = u" "

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

You can try via `re`.

Comment: not working.. despite i cant give test_str for each lines as am having many files like that..

Comment: @PavanChakravarthy you just have to read files one by one .put contents of file in one string through `f.read` and pass it to `re`.It works here see http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/44

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional list comprehension:

```
output = os.linesep.join(line for line in f if " " in line)
```

Comment: Upvoted, but you should explain what `os.linesep` is.